# How to write unit test case of ag agrid cellRenderer with return value in angular

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine, jasmine2.0

**TS:**

```
columnDefs = [
 { headerName: 'columnone', field: 'one', width: 120, sortable: true, 
   cellRenderer: (data) => {
        return this.limitCommonUtil.numberFormatter(data?.data?.upperAmount);
 }
    },
    { headerName: 'columntwo', field: 'two', width: 120, sortable: true,
      cellRenderer: (data) => {
        return this.limitCommonUtil.dateFormatterDDMMMYYYY(data?.data?.startDate);
      }]
```

**HTML:**

```
<ag-grid-angular
            [rowData]="(dataStream)"
            [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
            class="side-panels-container-grid"
            [gridOptions]="gridOptionsDefault"
            (selectionChanged)="onSelectionChanged()">
        </ag-grid-angular>
```

how to write unit test case for columndefs in jasmine and karma? am not able to cover cellRendered return function. Getting error as below.

**Error:**
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data') thrown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you mocked the data for the grid properly in your test? If you're only interested in unit testing the cellRenderer itself you can:

```
const cellRenderer = component.columnDefs.find(c => c.headerName === 'columnone').cellRenderer as any;
expect(cellRenderer({data: { upperAmount: 10 }})).toEqual('Whatever is expected');
```

Comment: I have tried your way, but got the error like "Expected Observable({ _isScalar: false, _subscribe: Function }) to equal 10."  @johan nordlinder

Comment: Oh, does this.limitCommonUtil.numberFormatter return an observable? I was expecting it to return a string.

Comment: do you have any idea on how to write expect case for that? @johan nordlinder

Comment: Can you show your current code, both the expect and the numberFormatter function?

Comment: but number formatter is returning number only.
 numberFormatter(value) {
    if (isNaN(value)) {
      return 0;
    } else {
      return Intl.NumberFormat().format(Math.round(value));
    }
  } @johan nordlinder

Comment: if you can, could you please check on the below link?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71428583/how-to-write-unit-test-case-for-function-call-inside-a-property-of-a-if-conditio
@johan nordlinder

Comment: Was facing the same issue as mentioned in the question, when I tried the accepted answer, I get an error "Object is possibly 'undefined'." How can I resolve this?